# Is there any way to load a component from filesystem in Oracle Commerce(ATG)?

Tags: java, atg, oracle-commerce

I'm trying to find out if we can load a oracle commerce component from file system. Generally we assemble all the code into an ear file and deploy it, however, I got a requirement where in I have to store some components in file system rather than packaging them along with ear file.

I know that we can use URLClassloader to load a class as shown below,

```
File classDir = new File("A:\\LodeeModule\\classes");
URL[] url = { classDir.toURI().toURL() };
ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(url);
for (File file : classDir.listFiles()) {
   String filename = file.getName().replace(".class", "");
   loader.loadClass("com.buddha.testers." + filename).getConstructor().newInstance();
}
```

but how can we use the same for an component which has to be resolved by Nucleus at later point of time? Is there any way to instruct Nucleus to resolve component from file system?

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to add the JAR that contains the components classes to the CLASSPATH system variable used by the application server instance.

Then in the component configuration just define the implementing class as you normally would

$class=some.class.path.class

If you are using Jboss EAP 6+ on a newer version of ATG (11.0+) you might have some more trouble, you have to jump through some more hoops due to its classloader

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7

Essentially you would need to define a jboss module containing your jar files, and define a dependency between the ear's "module" and the module containing your classes.

Alternatively you can define a ClassLoaderService that will manage the classes for your JARs

To do this, you need to define a new ClassLoaderService, so create a new properties file as you would with any other component.

/my/custom/ClassLoaderService.properties

```
$class=atg.nucleus.ServicesManifestClassLoaderService
$description=Custom Class Loader Service.
# The files to go into the classpath of the classloader 
classpathFiles=\ 
/path/to/my/jars/lib/someClasses.jar,\
/path/to/my/jars/lib/someOtherClasses.jar
loggingDebug=false
```

Then in the actual component that you need these classes for add this line;

```
$classloader=/my/custom/ClassLoaderService
```

Comment: Nice idea. I shall give it a try. Can we also use folder instead of jars?

Comment: Yes, instead of setting the classpathFiles property, you can set the jarDirectories property with the folder name/s

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the atg.dynamo.data-dir property.  If you specify that property dynamo will look at that location for the "server configs" or properties files.  This allows you to separate the configs from the ear file.

Note: You can still include configs in the ear, I believe they will still have first precedence

It's usually specified when you start the server, something like:

```
run.sh -c <your server> -Datg.dynamo.data-dir=/data/something/serverconfigs
```

This feature is largely undocumented, but many people know about it.
See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24152_01/Platform.10-1/ATGPlatformProgGuide/html/s0302developmentmodeandstandalonemode01.html

EDIT:
I mistook what you were originally asking.  You might want to take a look at the [disposable class loader](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24152_01/Platform.10-1/ATGPlatformProgGuide/html/s1901appendixadisposableclassloader01.html) that ATG provides, but keep in mind this is only intended for development purposes.

Comment: Hi Patrick, Thanks. But we already load the configs from folders, but how can it help us load a component? Like If we extend Generic Service and create a component and don't want to include this in ear file, not just the properties file but also the class file of the component.